Проблема с WebSocket
У меня есть функция отправки сообщения через WebSocket, но возникает проблема: при нажатии на кнопку отправки страница перезагружается. Вот мой код:
javascript
sendButton.onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Предотвращаем действие по умолчанию
    event.stopPropagation(); // Остановит дальнейшую обработку события
    console.log('Кнопка нажата'); // Проверка
    const message = messageInput.value.trim();

    if (message) {
        const data = {
            command: "sendMessage",
            user_id: userId,
            receiver: receiverId,
            text: message
        };

        socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        messageInput.value = ''; // Очищаем поле ввода после отправки
    }
};

HTML:
html
<div class="input-area">
    <input type="text" id="messageInput" placeholder="Введите сообщение...">
    <button class="send-button" id="sendButton" type="button">Отправить</button>
</div>

Серверная часть:
python
elif data["command"] == "sendMessage":
    sender = data["user_id"]
    receiver = data["receiver"]
    text = data["text"]
    await send_message_with_chat_creation(sender, receiver, text)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO messages (sender, receiver, text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (sender, receiver, text))
    conn.commit()

    await websocket.send_text(json.dumps({
        "status": "success",
        "command": "messageSent",
        "message": text
    }))

Несмотря на использование event.preventDefault(), при выполнении строки socket.send(JSON.stringify(data)); происходит перезагрузка страницы. Как это можно исправить?

В приведенном коде нет ничего, что могло бы перегрузить страницу

но она всеровно перезагружаеться

Поищите обработчик ответа сервера, может там стоит принудительный релоад? Сама отправка сообщения по сокету страницу не перегружает

Проблема в том, что вы не прерываете отправку, а прерываете событие клика, которого по сути то и нет.
onclick это не то же самое, что onsubmit.
Хотя в вашем коде я не вижу вообще form, и по идее браузер не должен вообще перезагружать страницу, но могу предположить, что вы просто не совсем точно приложили HTML код и там всё-таки есть форма которую браузер отправляет и надо гасить событие submit.
Можете попробовать так,
Обработчик на событие submit формы:
Если ваша кнопка находится в форме, вам следует предотвратить действие по умолчанию не только для кнопки, но и для всей формы:
const form = document.querySelector('.input-area'); // тут по идее селектор формы     
  form.onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Предотвращаем отправку формы
};

Ну и послушаем клик
sendButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log('Кнопка нажата');
const message = messageInput.value.trim();

if (message) {
    const data = {
        command: "sendMessage",
        user_id: userId,
        receiver: receiverId,
        text: message
    };

    socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    messageInput.value = '';
}
});


Ну так event.preventDefault() и так предотвратит сам клик...

@SwaD ну так нам здесь надо не клик предотвращать, а отправку. А это другое событие - submit. Раз страница перезагружается, вероятно это событие имеет место на странице

А если клика нет, как сабмит сработает то?

Не выходит, проблема именно в строчке socket.send(JSON.stringify(data)) без нее страница не перезагружается. Формы нету
